# IONotificationPortCreate function call generates compiler error

Tags: macos, swift, iokit

I am having an issue with the IONotificationCreatePort function in IOKit:

```
var NotificationPort = IONotificationPortCreate(MasterPort)
IONotificationPortSetDispatchQueue(NotificationPort, DispatchQueue)
```

gives the following compiler error when NotificationPort is used in the function call in the second line

> 'Unmanaged IONotificationPort' is not identical to
>   'IONotificationPort'

if I use the following code based on the information in the Using Swift with Cocoa and Objective-C document, it compiles but generates a runtime error

```
var NotificationPort = IONotificationPortCreate(MasterPort).takeRetainedValue()
IONotificationPortSetDispatchQueue(NotificationPort, DispatchQueue)
```

> Thread 1: EXC_BAD_ACCESS(code=1, address=0xwhatever)

So I think I have the run time error figured out, the IONotificationPort object does not have takeRetainedValue method

The crux of the problem as I see it, is that the IONotificationPortCreate function creates an IONotificationPort object and returns the reference to it.

I have looked all over the place and there is lots of information about and ways to pass references into a function call from Swift but nowhere can I find how to deal with references as a return value.

Can Swift call an object by reference?

Or am I way off the mark here????

Here is the objective C code that I am trying to convert to swift:

```
    _notificationPort = IONotificationPortCreate(masterPort);
    IONotificationPortSetDispatchQueue(_notificationPort, _controllerQueue);
```

Here is the complete code snippet from my swift file:

```
    //Get IOKit Master Port

    var MasterPort: mach_port_t = 0
    let BootstrapPort: mach_port_t = 0
    var MasterPortReturnCode: kern_return_t = 0

    MasterPortReturnCode = IOMasterPort(BootstrapPort, &MasterPort)
    println("Master port returned as \(MasterPort) with return code of \(MasterPortReturnCode)")

    //Set up notification port and send queue

    let DispatchQueue = dispatch_queue_create("com.apparata.AVB_Browser", DISPATCH_QUEUE_SERIAL)
    var NotificationPort = IONotificationPortCreate(MasterPort)
    IONotificationPortSetDispatchQueue(NotificationPort, DispatchQueue)
```

Comment: Are we sure that notification port isn't `nil`?

Comment: I am trying to convert an Objective C file to swift and in the Objective C code, there is no nil check as far as I can see. In my swift code, I am checking MasterPort for a value so I know it is not nil. In the documentation for IONotificationPortCreate is says the return value is : A reference to the notification object.

Comment: I found a lot of weirdnesses in doing things like this, have you tried logging all of your values to make sure they're what you expect?

Comment: OK, I am pretty new to this. As far as I can tell, NotificationPort is a reference to an object. How can I log this and what should I expect?

Comment: If I run the let DispatchQueue line in a playground, the playground hangs and if I run the var NotificationPort line in a playground, I get a runtime error: EXC_BAD_ACCESS(code=1,address=some address)

Comment: Hmm, sounds weird.  I might have more time to actually try this stuff later, difficult to diagnose without digging into it because I haven't used these APIs.  Won't have time for a bit.

Comment: I don't know much about Swift, but I should point out that in user space, Mach ports, including IOKit notification ports, are represented not as pointers, but as integer handles. They are most certainly not Objective-C runtime objects. Attempting to send any kind of Swift/Objective-C message to them is certainly going to end in tears.